# Cannot Resize Image in Canvas - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

First of all I've looked through all the similar questions and tried multiple times to get this to work but have had no luck. I'm trying to take a signature that I capture via a canvas element on either a desktop or mobile device and resize it. Because the device sizes are different, so is my canvas for each device. Before I save the signature image, I want to resize it so that all my saved images are the same size.

Here is the code I currently have.

```
resize(){
    var image = new Image();
    var t = this;
    image.onload = function(){

        image.width = '100px';
        image.height = 'auto';

        t.canvas.width = image.width;
        t.canvas.height = image.height;

        t.ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0);    
        console.log(t.canvas.toDataURL());
        return t.canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    image.src = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  
}
```

This code doesn't produce any errors, however after I "resize" the image, `canvas.toDataURL();` returns "data:," rather than the image. Before I attempt the resize, I am able to grab a valid png image from `this.canvas.toDataURL();`.

I also tried changing the style width and height but this causes my canvas to reset which causes my image to disappear.

```
this.canvas.style.width = 100;
this.canvas.style.height = 100;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

I've put together a Codepen here that shows the original image on the left and on the right you will see that same image that I have attempted to resize with JavaScript. I added an orange background for readability purposes only.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cannonmoyer/pen/JQdWWG)

Comment: Can you post a working example of your code? I didn't really get what's going wrong.

Comment: This is normal since `toDataURL` returns a data URI containing a representation of the image in the format specified by the type parameter, see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: @tjc I understand this, but if I update the canvas and draw a brand new image like I have in the code above then why would it be null?

Comment: One should have a working snippet of your code (HTML + JS) to have a better idea of your issue.

Comment: @tcj I've updated the question to include a Codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I could spot in your codepen is this line

```
context.drawImage(img,200,150);
```

The values 200 and 150 specify the position on the canvas where the image should be drawn. This essentially draws it ouside the visible area.

If you change it to

```
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

it works as the second pair of numbers is the clipping area.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 150;
  img.width = 200;
  img.height = 150;
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = document.getElementById("theImg").src;
```

```css
canvas {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<img id="theImg" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```